# GeoJSON --> TopoJSON conversion for Point geometries?

Tags: geojson, topojson

I am trying to use the command-line topojson tool from Mike Bostock to convert a GeoJSON feature collection with Point features to TopoJSON, but coordinates in the input files does not seem to be picked up correctly since output coordinates turn out as [null,null] in the output. The GeoJSON file contains spherical coordinates in WGS84 and displays correctly when loaded into Leaflet.

I have tried several commands, for instance this

```
topojson --spherical -o topo.json geo.json
```

The input file is

http://www.skiforeningen.no/marka/bilder/geo/geo.json

Do I need to tell topojson more about the input crs and the conversion? It is all defined in the input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GeoJSON file is broken, the coordinates are strings instead of numbers. You can fix it with this Python script:

```
import json
with open('geo.json', 'rb') as f:
    geo = json.load(f)

for f in geo['features']:
    geometry = f['geometry']
    geometry['coordinates'] = [float(n) for n in geometry['coordinates']]

with open('geo3.json', 'wb') as f:
    json.dump(geo, f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have seen that, but the file was in fact generated by the Perl module Geo::JSON, which converts Perl data structures to GeoJSON. The coordinates were floating point numbers in the input data. Thanks for creating that nifty little Python snippet which cleaned the file. Now the cleaned file converts as it should to TopoJSON.